# Django error whike migrate in heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, github

I keep getting this error when I try to do migrate in my heroku django project:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration BaseApp.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('conversation', '0010_auto_20160501_0202')
```

any idea how to deal with it or atleast how to delete this reference?

ps: I get this after I migrate locally' commit and trying to migrate on heroku

Comment: Look at your `0001_initial` migration file, and see if there is a dependency matching the latter migration name in the error. An obvious reading is that you just don't have a migration that matches that dependency. Maybe it didn't get committed to source control for some reason. It also might be that the missing migration comes from some kind of library that you're trying to use, which could also have some kind of common cause for not getting its migration files committed. Again, speculating here. I also take it that "after I migrate locally" means you did `makemigrations`.

Comment: i see that "('conversation', '0010_auto_20160501_0202')"  in my0001_initial dependencies. how can I delete it? (its actually does belong to an external library im using). any idea how to solve it?

Comment: If you have not ran `manage.py makemigrations`, absolutely try that. Also, that external library probably has to be in your `INSTALLED_APPS ` list, if it is not already. Then, obviously, you may want to followup with the docs for the app which says `./manage.py migrate conversation`, from https://github.com/bitmazk/django-conversation